# Using loops to find all matching objects in watir

Tags: ruby, rspec, watir

I'm trying to make a script that looks for all instances of an element within a table by looping through. I can identify *one* object, the first instance of it:

```
b.table(id: "table_id").a.title
=> "foo bar"
```

but when I attempt to loop through the table, I run into issues:

```
def get_titles
  titles = ""
  b.table(id: "table_id").a.title.each do |title|
    titles << title
  end
  puts titles
end

get_titles
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "foo bar":String
```

I believe there is something wrong with how I'm attempting to loop through the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Correct way is :

```
def get_titles
  titles = ""
  b.tables(id: "table_id").each do |table|
    titles << table.a.title
  end
  puts titles
end
```

`b.table(id: "table_id").a.title` gave you a `String` object, and you called `#each` on this string object. That's why the error.

As per the [Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462750/using-loops-to-find-all-matching-objects-in-watir#comment45252856_28462832) comment, clear way is :

```
b.table(id: "table_id").links.map(&:title).join
```

Comment: You will still get an exception since Watir::Table also does not have an `each` method. Perhaps you meant to use a Watir::TableCollection - ie should be `b.tables` instead of `b.table`. Though I would guess that the question is actually looking to loop through links of a single table (since multiple tables should not have the same id) - ie something like `b.table(id: "table_id").links.map(&:title).join`.

Comment: @JustinKo Go ahead. I'll down it :-)

Comment: @JustinKo that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. (Thanks to you too, Arup.)

Comment: Dan: if this answer addressed your problem, you should accept it.  That way JustinKo will get credit...uhhh...actually @Arup will get the credit...either way, you should accept the answer ;)

Comment: @orde Oh! I meant to accept but stepped away from the computer. How embarrassing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments to the other answer, the problem is that you are trying to use the .each method on a single object instead of some form of collection.

To get a collection holding all the titles from inside some container, use the .titles method

```
titles = b.tables(id: "table_id").titles

if you need something like a collection of all the text of the titles

b.tables(id: "table_id").titles.each do |title|
  titles << title.text
end
```

You can also use something like Justin gave in his comment to the first answer